# Breezair EX swamp cooler not moving air, how to debug the motor and fan?

Tags: evaporative-cooling

new homeowner and the weather means I can't get a technician out for weeks. Hoping there might be an opportunity to learn a bit and get this thing running on my own.

**History**

- been here since last September. Cooler worked fine through fall until I turned it off for winter. Recently switched it on and it was blowing air but I noticed it seemed to stop too soon and not come back on until I turned it off and waited overnight.
- when I turned it on recently I did hear a lot of excessive noise and a squeaking/grinding type noise that would present on start up and resolve in a few minutes. This is when I *should have* called someone, but too late for that now.

**Behavior**

- water seems to be good. I've checked the reservoir, the fill line, the float valve etc. The pump will kick on and soak the pads, I can hear it intermittently in the back yard. Last time I went up to check the pump to soak the pads was running and everything was wet, reservoir was full.
- the fan won't come on. The controller I have inside isn't super sophisticated, but I have switched it often from Auto to Manual and switched cool OFF so that I could just run the fan in the Vent setting -- nothing.

My gut, and what very little I understand about swamp coolers, tells me that the fan is the issue. However, all of what that could encompass I'm in the dark about. Are there wires I should test first? Breakers to check? Switches to toggle?

Comment: I know nothing about your particular model. Generically, it might need lubrication (the squeaking) a replacement belt if it uses belt-type reduction drive, and might have a motor thermal cutout that might need to be reset (often a pushbutton somewhere on the motor housing) from overheating while trying to run the fan while poorly lubricated.

Comment: Awesome, I have some lubrication, can look for a belt, and look for some buttons on the motor/motor housing to look for. That should get me started!